# Why is the mode of the Dirichlet not the same as the modes of its marginals?

Tags: marginal-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, mode

The mode of a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots \alpha_N$, $\alpha_i > 1$ is:

$$x_i = \frac{\alpha_i - 1}{\alpha_0 - N}$$.

Where $\alpha_0 = \sum_k{\alpha_k}$. But its marginal distributions are $\text{Beta}(\alpha_i, \alpha_0 - \alpha_i)$, which have these modes:

$$x_i = \frac{\alpha_i - 1}{\alpha_0 - 2}$$

So I guess my question is: isn't that weird? The means are the same for example. I'm having a hard time building an intuition for this. Wouldn't the maximums of the marginals form the maximum of the complete pdf?

edit: I found [this interesting article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.822.4327&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which talks a bit about this question. But I'd still like an answer to my original question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the following example will help explain. Consider a 2-dimensional random vector $X$. $X$ is distributed as follows. w.p. 1/3 $X=(0,0)$ w.p. 1/4 $X=(1,2)$ w.p. 1/4 $X=(1,1)$ w.p. 1/12 $X=(2,1)$ w.p. 1/12 $X=2,2$. The mode here is $(0,0)$ but the marginal modes are 1 and 0 respectively. The reason for the discrepancy is that the elements are dependent. When the first element is 0 then the other element is always zero, which makes $(0,0)$ have high probability. The first element is more likely to be 1 than 0, but when it is 1 the second element could be 2 or 1 with equal probability, so $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are individually less probable than $(0,0)$.

Note that if random variables are independent the marginal modes will correspond to the joint mode. This is because the joint probability is $\prod_i P_i(x_i)$ which is maximized by the $x_i$s that maximize their respective marginal probabilities $P_i$.